# How do you make the sender display name appear with JSQMessageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have the following function that gets called for adding a message:

```
    func addMessage(text: String, displayName: String) {
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: "tester", displayName: displayName, text: text)
        messages.append(message)

        finishReceivingMessage()

}
```

Then in this function

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
    messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
}
```

I return the message date for that indexPath. The message appears correctly but there is no display name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are missing the `attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath` should look something like this

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView?, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    switch message.senderId {
    case CURRENTUSERID:
        return nil
    default:
        guard let senderDisplayName = message.senderDisplayName else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }
        return NSAttributedString(string: senderDisplayName)
        
    }
}
```

Edit:

Also make sure you give the label a hight with this function

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
   return 13 //or what ever height you want to give
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just had to add another function as well to specify the height of the top label.

Comment: @Tob could you please post the function you used to specify the height of the top label?

Comment: This is what I used:    
       `override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        return 15
    }`

Comment: Just type "collectionView" and you should be able to scroll down until you find heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath (There is also a function to specify the height of the top label).

Comment: For those who are looking to have the `NSAttributedString` appear on the top of the message bubble, override the `heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath` method. The `heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath ` sets the height above the bubble, but not the bubble's top label.

Comment: Thanks @Tob I added that to the answer.

Comment: @DanielLeonard I see that you know your thinkg when it comes to JSQMessageViewController. Could you please help me understand why I get no sound when trying to play a video message in a JSQMessageViewController? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911924

Comment: @bibscy I don't have any experience with that specific implementation. But I will take a look and see what I can do.

Comment: @DanielLeonard  I have found out. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

New Updated Methods

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString!
     {
        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        if message.senderId == senderId {
            return nil
        } else {
            guard let senderDisplayName = message.senderDisplayName else {
                assertionFailure()
                return nil
            }
            return NSAttributedString(string: senderDisplayName)

        }

    }

     override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat
    {
        //return 17.0
        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        if message.senderId == senderId {
            return 0.0
        } else {

            return 17.0

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I was looking for, however, there occurs an error. It gives back an error, saying, that initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not String. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this function in order to display the name:

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for swift 3

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
        return  NSAttributedString(string: senderDisplayName)
    }

     override  func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        return 15 //your height
    }
```